# How to pass a list and other values as command line arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass 4 arguments to my python script and one of them has to be a list. Even if it just contains 1 element.

The order of the arguments does not matter.

```
    import sys
    print sys.argv

    one = sys.argv[1]
    two = sys.argv[2]
    three = sys.argv[3]
    four = sys.argv[4]

    print "one: " + one
    print "two: " + two
    print "three: "+ three
    print "four: " + four
```

This is how I am calling it.

```
    python myScript.py name file setting ['listItem1']
```

Where the fourth item is the list with one element. However when I print it I see

```
    four: [listItem1]
```

I would like to see

```
    four: ['listItem1']
```

Comment: I hope you are not planning to `eval` that last argument...

Comment: The variable `four` isn't a list, it's a string containing the value `'[listItem1]'`.

Comment: We have optparse, argparse modules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as PersonArtPhoto pointed out, you need to escape the qutoation marks to prevent the shell from using them itself.

What you're going to wind up with in your program is a string that resembles a list, which isn't what you want

```
import sys 

four = sys.argv[4]
print four[2]
```

shows

```
$ python myscript.py one two three [\'first\',\'second\']
f
```

this `'f'` is coming from indexing `"['first','second']"` because it is just a string of characters

---

one way to make python interpret this is `eval` but it is **highly discouraged** as it is extremely **insecure**.  `eval` interprets a string as code, so it shouldn't be used on user input because the user can enter *anything* and python will execute it.

```
import sys 

four = eval(sys.argv[4])
print four[1]
```

shows

```
$ python myscript.py one two three [\'first\',\'second\']
second
```

---

instead I suggest a safer approach.  Use a *command line flag* to signal that you are sending the list of arguments

```
import sys

# make sure the --args flag was passed
if '--args' not in sys.argv:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Please pass the "--args" flag followed by a list of'\
            ' arguments'
    sys.exit(1) #terminate execution if it wasn't

four = sys.argv[sys.argv.index('--args')+1:] # everything passed after --args
print four
```

shows

```
$ python myscript.py one two three --args 'first' 'second'
['first', 'second']
```

---

if you know that there will always be three args before your list, you can simply use a slice

```
import sys

one, two, three = sys.argv[1:4] # grab indicies 1, 2, and 3
four = sys.argv[4:]
print one
print two
print three
print four
```

shows

```
$ python myscript.py one two three 'first' 'second'
one
two
three
['first', 'second']
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a better method is to call your script like

```
python myScript.py name file setting listItem1 ...
```

And then use, instead, a slice:

```
four = sys.argv[4:]
```

This keeps python syntax out of the shell, which is ugly, and may cause more troubles later down the track with special characters in the shell.

An even better method would be to implement a proper CLI using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotations

```
python myScript.py name file setting [\'listItem1\']
```

Comment: You may want to add *why*. (... because the shell is interpreting these ...)

Comment: It's always going to be a string. The shell gives you a string. The fact that it's a string with brackets in it doesn't make it a list.

Answer (score 1):

**Program:**

```
import sys, ast, getopt, types

def main(argv):            
    arg_dict={}
    switches={'li':list,'di':dict,'tu':tuple}
    singles=''.join([x[0]+':' for x in switches])
    long_form=[x+'=' for x in switches]
    d={x[0]+':':'--'+x for x in switches}
    try:            
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, singles, long_form)
    except getopt.GetoptError:          
        print "bad arg"                       
        sys.exit(2)       

    for opt, arg in opts:        
        if opt[1]+':' in d: o=d[opt[1]+':'][2:]
        elif opt in d.values(): o=opt[2:]
        else: o =''
        print opt, arg,o
        if o and arg:
            arg_dict[o]=ast.literal_eval(arg)

        if not o or not isinstance(arg_dict[o], switches[o]):    
            print opt, arg, " Error: bad arg"
            sys.exit(2)                 

    for e in arg_dict:
        print e, arg_dict[e], type(arg_dict[e])        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Command line:**

```
python py.py --l='[1,2,3,[1,2,3]]' -d "{1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}" --tu='(1,2,3)'
```

**Output:**

```
args:  ['--l=[1,2,3,[1,2,3]]', '-d', "{1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}", '--tu=(1,2,3)']
tu (1, 2, 3) <type 'tuple'>
di {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'} <type 'dict'>
li [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]] <type 'list'>
```

This code snippet will take short or long command switches like `-l` or `--li=` and parse the text after the switch into a Python data structure like a list, tuple or a dict. The parsed data structure ends up in a dictionary with the long-form switch key.

Using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) is relatively safe. It can only parse python data definitions.

Comment: that example only passes lists with no extra values. and is main accepting three lists? or one list?

Comment: @Siecje: To take the part of this program and integrate into the way you are doing the first three positional arguments is trivial. Just call the function with `sys.argv[4:]` and parse from there...